# How are reference types cleared from memory?

Tags: c#, .net, memory, heap-memory

As objects are reference types they are stored in the heap and primitive data types are store on the stack.

But an object is a collection of primitive datatypes as well reference type i.e. a object may have a integer data member and/or may have another object within it.

When the scope ends the primitive data memory is released from the stack but the heap memory is handled by the garbage collector.

Now my question is: if an object also has a primitive data member then when are they removed?

Comment: I suggest you read [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx) series of articles by Eric Lippert. Lots of people get hung up on reference type = heap allocation, value type = stack allocation.

Comment: @madan `Code formatting` is only intended for code, not emphasis. Emphasis is usually unnecessary anyway, especially in cases such as yours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As objects are reference types they are stored in the heap and primitive data types are store on the stack.

Not quite. *Value types*, which includes the primitives, but also `struct` types are stored on the stack when they are locals. They can also be stored on the heap if boxed or in an array or, as you note, a field of a reference type.

Reference types have one or more references which might also be stored on the stack—the local(s) you address it through—and the representation of the object itself on the heap.

> When the scope ends the primitive data memory is released from the stack but the heap memory is handled by the garbage collector.

Not quite.

First, there isn't really a "releasing" operation. Say we were using 4 slots on the stack to store the values 1-4*:

```
[1][2][3][4][ ][ ][ ][ ]
          ^
       Using up to here.
```

(I'm going to completely ignore the matter of what happens between function calls for the sake of simplicity).

Now say we stop using the last 2 slots. There's no need to "release" anything:

```
[1][2][3][4][ ][ ][ ][ ]
    ^
  Using up to here.
```

Only if we go to, e.g. use 1 new slot to store the value 5, need we overwrite anything:

```
[1][2][5][4][ ][ ][ ][ ]
       ^
     Using up to here.
```

The "releasing" just changed which memory was considered in use and which considered available.

Now consider the following C# code:

```
public void WriteOneMore(int num)
{
  int result = num + 1;
  Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Say you call that with the value `42`. The relevant portion of the stack is:

```
[42]
 ^
 Using up to here.
```

Now, after `int result = num + 1;` there are two values in scope; `result` and `num`. As such the stack might be:

```
[42][43]
     ^
   Using up to here.
```

However, `num` is never used again. The compiler and jitter know this, so they *might* have reused the same slot:

```
[43]
 ^
 Using up to here.
```

Because "in scope" refers to the source code, and what variables **can be** used in particular places, but the stack is used according to what variables actually **are** used in particular places, so it can often use less stack space than the source may suggest. Conversely, sometimes you find the same variable becoming more than one slot, if it makes things easier for the compiler in some way. This is no big deal here, but becomes important when we come to reference types.

> the heap memory is handled by the garbage collector.

Let's consider what that actually means.

If an application needs heap memory for new objects, it takes that memory from a free part of a heap. If there isn't enough heap memory available it could ask the OS for more, but before that it may try garbage collecting.

When this happens, first the garbage collector makes a note of what heap-stored (reference types including boxed value types) objects it **can't** get rid of.

One set of such objects are those that are in a `static` variable.

Another is those that are in reachable parts of the stack. So if the stack is like:

```
["a"]["b"]["c"]["d"]["e"]
            ^
          Using up to here.
```

Then the values `"a"`, `"b"` and `"c"` cannot be collected.

The next set is any object that can be reached via a field of one of the objects that it already knows can't be collected, or through a field in one of those, and so on.

(A final step is any object that isn't ineligible due to the above, which needs to be finalised, they get put on the finalisation queue here, so they'll be eligible after the finaliser thread has dealt with them).

Now. On the heap, the object looks a bit like;

```
[Sync][RTTI][Field0][Field1]  … [FieldN]
```

Here "Sync" marks the sync block used if you lock on the object. "RTTI" marks a pointer to type information, used to obtain the type and to enable virtual methods to work. The rest is fields, whether value-types contained directly or references to other reference types.

Okay. Let's say this object is one that the collector decides it can collect.

It simply changes that block of memory from being considered not available to use, to being available to use. That's it.

In a subsequent step all in-use objects get moved together to compact the used memory into one block and the free into another. Our old object might be overwritten at this point, or it might not be overwritten for some time to come. We don't really care, because the corpse of that dead object is just a bunch of 1s and 0s sitting there doing nothing now, waiting for the palimpsest of volatile memory to be written to once more.

So the primitive fields are released at the point where the object's memory is considered available to use, but again, they may still be present in RAM for some time, or not, they're just ignored.

It's worth remembering, that just as the values on the stack may not correspond to what is "in scope" in the source code, so therefore an object can be collected while it's in scope; garbage collection depends on the real use of the stack, not the source. This mostly doesn't affect anything, because most attempts to use something in the code means that it is now part of the real use of the stack and therefore won't be collected. Of the very few cases where it can affect something probably the most common is an attempt to use a `Timer` that is only referenced through a local; the main thread doesn't use it any more so that stack space can be used up and then the timing thread finds no such timer. This is where `GC.KeepAlive()` comes in.

*When it comes to the running code, locals might be stored in registers and never actually in the stack of memory. At the level of considering how the .NET code works, it's generally easiest just to consider them also "on the stack". At the level of considering how the machine code works, that's not true. When the garbage collector looks at what is "on the stack" to see what it can't delete, it also looks at what references are in registers.

Answer (score 1):

It is very hard to explain such a fundamental but not always easy to understand things. However in the last 15 years many good explanation was written.

In case you do not want to read them (obviously...) here is a very short and (consequently not complete) wrap up: (note: still I strongly recommend to investigate toward in the literature)

Note: The following part is edited slightly based on comment conversation about "primitive type" terminology:

**(edit)**
In this question's context it is more appropriate to talk about "value type" instead of "primitive type". Regardless of the type is primitive or not, it only matters is it value type or reference type in this context.
**(end edit)**

Now the point:

Reference type have a reference (anywhere, like in heap or stack) which points the instance allocated *always* on the heap. Value type are stored (anywhere, like in the heap or stack) immediately *embedded* that place, so there is no indirection.

Samples:

- Local variable of a value type: stack
- Local variable of a reference type: instance itself on the heap, and the reference is on the stack
- Member variable (value type): Embedded into the allocated space of the  instance which's member variable it is.
- Member variable (reference type): Its reference embedded into the allocated space of the  instance which's member variable it is, *and* *its* *instance* on the heap.

> Now my question is: if an object also has a primitive data member then when are they removed?

Answer: When the containing object is removed. (Hopefully it is clear based on the 4 samples: The containing object can be on the heap or on the stack, so the "containing object removal" could be a GC collection or a simple stack pointer set when returning from a method.)

Comment: The expression "primitive type" appears many times in ECMA-335, so there certainly is such a thing in .NET. In ECMA-334 "primitive" only appears in quotes, so there's nothing defined as "primitive" but the concept certainly isn't inapplicable.

Comment: The expression "primitive type" appears _only_ one time in the ECMA-335 (http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf) and not as a definition neither as a topic tittle. The "value type" appears 379 times, many times as a topic tittle and as a defined entity. Decide it is appropriate to use it or not, and also decide is there anything even similar in .NET as Java primitive types, then decide is it misleading to use this term in context of .NET or not, especially when you would like to explain some fundamental architecture thing.

Comment: I was also including "primitive and non -primitive value types", "primitive or value type", "primitive numeric type", "primitive numeric types" in my count. In this case there's no difference between primitives and other values types, but you can't say there's no such thing in .NET.

Comment: @Jon: OK I understand your point.. Also, we _agree_ about "this case there's no difference". My point is: there are many confusing "text" out there and most of them miss the point (or at least cloudy) by using inappropriate terminology. (plus add: "built in types" (my favorite :-)).